# R drop adjacent columns based on a column value

Tags: r

I have a df say 
Df1

```
Col1 col2 Col3 col 4 
Match 1 1 4
Match 1 1 4
Match 1 1 4
```

Now I want to check if any col contains string "match" if so then I need to delete col1 and its adjacent columns col2 and col2 only and still retain column 4

Any help would be appreciated 
So the output should like 
Df1

```
Col4
4
4
4
```

Comment: You need to  keep all the columns in the dataframe , otherwise how do you plan to retain them when col1 does not have 'match'?  What you can do is 'delete' these values by replacing them  NA . It would be helpful to explain how the output is intended to be used.

Comment: Can u tel me how to rename  as NA for col1 and apply same for adjacent columns. Note for sample I dint mention all cold, but my cold list will be huge say abt 100 columns. In that case how can do it. I am fine with replacing them as NA and then remove it at the end by using omit.na . But I need to know how I can apply a logic to adjacent columns based on 1 col

Comment: Here col1 is resultant of col2 and col2.  I.e. if col2 = Col3 then col1 =match , and so on for the other alternate cols like if col5 !=col6 then col4 = mismatch. So intent is to drop columns that have match and retain those that have mismatch

Comment: So you want to drop duplicate columns, i.e. where the whole of one column is exactly like another? (and here too, ideally you will perhaps need to retain one of those columns instead of deleting both)

Comment: Just help me on how to drop an adjacent column based on above explanation and will sort the rest  thanks

Comment: To drop a column, just use `df$mycol<- NULL` . Can try this - `if(all(df$col2==df$Col3)) df$col2<- NULL` which says if col2 is exactly like col3 , remove col2